# UICollectionViewCell Subclass issue

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have subclassed a UICollectionViewCell-

```
@interface ListCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *lblAppName;
@end
```

I have made an xib for the same ,made all the IBOutlet collection  as well as set the class of the XIB , while using this Cell in the Collection view delegate method i get a nill value while trying to access the label instance.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

ListCell *cell = (ListCell *)[cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ListCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
AppDetails *temp=[arrApplist objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
cell.lblAppName.text=temp.strName;
return cell;
}
```

i have registered the cell to my collection view by:

```
[collectionView registerClass:[ListCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ListCell"];
```

is there something else i might be missing??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of registering the class, I think you need to register the xib, using registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:. Try that, and see if that helps.

Comment: Hi it did thanks but had to register both the class and the xib

Answer (score 1):

if you use ListCell.xib,please use registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:.
Implement your ListCell initial in awakeFromNib instead of initWithFrame.
And change type like that:

```
- (ListCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
ListCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ListCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.lblAppName.text=(NSString *); 
return cell; 
}
```